# Azure Account "Add Role Assignment" Disabled

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I have the following permissions in my Azure account

[image]

But when I want to "add a role assignment for an Application" I noticed that my account for adding roles has been disable, see image

[image]

Can someone let me know if it's actually possible to add a application while my account to add roles has been disabled?

Comment: Please note that, you should have either [User Access Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator) or [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner) permissions to add role assignment. It's not possible without having these roles. Refer **[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current#prerequisites)**

Comment: Sridev, thanks for reaching out. Is it possible with the permissions I currently have to assign myself "User Access Administrator" or "Owner permissions"?

Comment: With your permissions, you cannot assign those roles. You should contact the person with **Global Administrator** role to have those permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, to assign **roles** to any resource in Azure Portal, you should have either **`Owner`** or **`User Access Administrator`** roles on your Azure subscription.

- **`Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write`** permissions are included in these roles that allows to assign roles.
- **Global Administrator** has the rights to assign these roles.
- As you have only **Contributor** role, you cannot assign roles, but you can create and manage resources.
- You must contact the person with **Global Administrator/Privileged Role Administrator** role to assign those permissions for you.

Please check the below from [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#azure-roles):

[image]

After acquiring any of those 2 roles, **`Add role assignment`** option will be enabled.

You can check the below **references** for more details:

[Assign Azure roles using the Azure portal - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current#prerequisites)

[Assign Azure AD roles to users - Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/manage-roles-portal)